# White bars at the top and bottom of extension when opened in chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just started developing an extension earlier today and when I checked how it would look within the browser I noticed these white spaces at the top and bottom. I noticed similar but smaller spaces in other chrome extensions I have. I can't seem to find anything online about it. Does anyone know what's going on and how I can fix it?

Here's a picture for reference:

[image that shows a picture of extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a4xO.png)

The white space at the right side isn't part of the problem it was just the way I captured the picture.

--Question was answered by wOxxOm in comments below.

Comment: The one on top is the border shown in Windows OS, you can't remove it. The same thin one is at the bottom. As for the thick bar at the bottom, this is most likely caused by your extension's CSS so you need to add [MCVE](/help/mcve) into the question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I didn't think it was CSS because I added different colours to all elements and it didn't show up in the window I am viewing in. However, I removed a padding style from the CSS and it fixed the issue. It sucks that I can't fix the bars but at least I don't have the big white area at the bottom!. Thanks again.